# Como carregar conteúdo de arquivo json remoto na unity 5?

Tags: unity-5

Eu tenho 60 urls, porém o www.text só me retorna 45. Eu não tenho erros.

Abaixo está o meu código.

```
public class LoadPhoto : MonoBehaviour {

     private string LinkJsonFile = "http://www.bollyshake.com/api/1/video/trending?page=2&per_page=60";
     void Start () {
         position = 0;
         StartCoroutine(UploadImages(LinkJsonFile));
     }

     IEnumerator UploadImages (string LinkJsonFile)
    {
        string aux = "";
        WWW www = new WWW (LinkJsonFile);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        if (www.isDone) {
            aux = www.text;
            print (aux);
            if (www.text == null) {
                Debug.Log ("Url de images são nulas");
            }
        }

    }
```

}

Há uma outra maneira para fazer isso ?

Obrigada pela ajuda.